# I can't fetch any images or show any URL image in my website

Tags: javascript, meteor, amazon-s3, cross-domain

Whenever I try to fetch an image URL from the database to the client, I get this error:

```
Refused to load the image 'https://nuclear-photos.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/…22:33:44%20GMT+0400%20(GST)TEST.png'
 because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data: 'self' http://*.s3.amazonaws.com https://*.s3.amazonaws.com".
```

What is causing this problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you have the `browser-policy` package installed.  Fix it by adding this line of code on your server:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("nuclear-photos.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");
```

This tells your browser policy to allow anything from this domain (presumably your own S3 bucket).